# Disqus universal code for Django

Tags: django, disqus

I try to install disqus in my site, but nothing is displayed on the page. Site url - [djaway.net](http://djaway.url)
This is my code:

**views.py**

```
def detail(request, slug):
    url = (reverse('content:detail', args=[slug]))
    content_info = Post.objects.get(slug =  slug)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'content_info':content_info, 'url':url})
```

**template.html**

```
<script>

    var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = 'djaway.net{{ url }}';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = '{{ url }}'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
    };

    (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'djaway.disqus.com/embed.js';
    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

Tag `{{ url }}` return right links, for example `/content/slug/`

Comment: Is there anything in the console of your browser's developer tools? Try including the scheme in the URL, e.g. `https://djaway.net{{url}}`

Comment: In console of developer tools I have message  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for this link http://djaway.net/content/ispolzovanie-middleware-v-django/djaway.disqus.com/embed.js

Comment: Note it's not recommended to run your site with `DEBUG = True` on a publicly accessible website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `https://` in the URL for loading the disqus javascript:

```
s.src = 'https://djaway.disqus.com/embed.js';
```

It might be a good idea to include `http://` or `https://` (depending on whether your site uses https):

```
this.page.url = 'https://djaway.net{{ url }}';
```